# Как правильно задать z-index слоям?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь разобраться в логике работы `z-index`, пока не получается...

Набросал несколько слоев, задача следующая: `.alerts` должен быть под `.content`, но `.alerts__alert` (`.alerts` -> `.alerts__alert`) должен быть над `.content`.

Собственно, по указанным `z-index`, наложение слоев должно быть понятно более наглядно.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #ead2ca;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.alerts {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.alerts__alert {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #bee7ea;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.</p>
  <p>Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот.</p>
  <p>Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики.</p>
  <p>Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу.</p>
</div>

<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alerts__alert">Alert!</div>
</div>
```

В итоге, `.alerts__alert` находится под `.content`, хотя `z-index` у него больше... Как быть?

Comment: сделать чтобы `z-index` у `alerts` был больше чем  `z-index` у `cintent`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц тогда `.alerts` будет перекрывать `.content`

Comment: а вам вообще что нужно?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц порядок наложения слоев так: `.alerts` под `.content`, а `.alerts__alert` над `.content`, при этом желательно сохранить структуру `html`...

Comment: на сколько я знаю так не работает...они не на одном уровне дерева

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц понял, спасибо! Отпишите, как ответ - выберу решением...